# Curl Auth Retornando Carcteres Estranhos

Tags: php, json, api, libcurl, oauth2

Olá,
Estou acessando uma api que ao enviar um auth2 com clientId e clientSecret é recebido o token para validação em outras requisições;
O problema é que ao receber o token não consigo visualizar os caracteres, assim não posso salvar e utilizar depois.
Segue o código em php:

```
    $rota = "http://xxx.com.br/authentication/v1.0/oauth/token";

    $data = http_build_query(['grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'clientId' => $clientId, 'clientSecret' => $clientSecret]);

    $process = curl_init($rota);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $resp = curl_exec($process);
    $err = curl_error($process);

    var_dump($resp);
```

A saída é algo:

string(91) "�J�/R�IRrJL J-,M-.Q�M-.NL {�%�d�(�%�(�T��

Já havia visto outra pergunta parecida com a minnha aqui no fórum, utilizei o código mas continuo com o mesmo problema, colocando echo, print_r, a saída é sempre os caracteres estranhos;
Estou utlizando a API do Ifood, e nesta primeira requisição é utilizado o comando cURL:

```
    curl -X POST "https://xxx/authentication/v1.0/oauth/token" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grantType=client_credentials&clientId=1111&clientSecret=1111&authorizationCode=&authorizationCodeVerifier="
```

> Documentação da API: https://developer.ifood.com.br/docs/references#operations-OAuth-oauthTokenV1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Adcionar no código;